# How to read .eph (GPS Ephemeris binary data) sent by the receiver

Tags: gps, ephemeris, raw-data

My GPS receiver can share ephemeris info as binary data. The queried data is having .eph format. I tried to open it in Notepad but seems unreadable (gibberish). Is there any specific software to open this ephemeris.eph file?

Comment: Can you edit and include the make and model of your GPS receiver ? The only hits I was getting that weren't to the JPL planetary ephemerides or generic info about the almanac that is in the messages were for Trimble's [GPS Pathfinder Office](https://forms.trimble.com/globalTRLTAB.aspx?Nav=Collection-4552)

Comment: if you have a Linux system handy, [the file command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) is pretty nice for identifying if it's an existing file type with a recognizable header.  If not, it could just be a binary data blob

Comment: If file contains only binary values then [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) tool might be also very handy for your situation. As far as I know HxD can be downloaded both for Window and Linux.